# Separated two component in Alert Dialog window

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to separate into two parts the components of alert dialog as it's shown in the image below.

i.e. "Ok" button separated from main body

[image]

Comment: What if you just create transparent alert dialog with main body and OK button in it?

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky  I didn't get your answer. Please, could clarify it a bit

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky I didn't understand how can I separate 'ok' button from the main body

Comment: there is no limitation to do this, you are not thinking outside the box, there exists a color Colors.transperent which will make the background of the dialogue transperent and set elevation to 0, content should be two containers, second container's shape should be circle, thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go a working code

```
class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      body: Dialog(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 256,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            FlatButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text("OK"),shape: const CircleBorder(),color: Colors.white,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```